# NavController How to replace menu fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, bottomnavigationview

I have 3 Fragments. `Home - Search - Login` . `Login` section successful process to redirect to `Profile`. Using Nav Graph.

```
findNavController().navigate(R.id.fragment_profile)
```

As a result current scenario of **`BottomNavigationView`** is

`Home - Search - Profile`

Now, If user click back in this situation then `Profile` section to open `Home` as expected. But user click on `Profile` menu then old `Login` fragment appear. How can i solve this issue. I want to set **Profile fragment** instead of **Login fragment** on runtime.

**FYI**

If I reload app then this problem will not occur, I have set below logic

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
   If Logged{
            menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_profile, menu)
        } else {
            menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_login, menu)
        }
    }
    bottomBar.setupWithNavController(menu!!, navController)

    return true
}
```

Please Help me out.

Answer (score 0):

The **onCreateOptionsMenu** is called before the **onCreate** of your activity ends. That means whatever was set when the activity was created will stay that way unless the **onCreate** of your activity is called again. Like you mentioned that the problem is resolved if you reload the app. This causes the activity to be created again which in turn causes the **onCreateOptionsMenu** to be called again.

What you need to do is to manually recreate the menu when you know that the user is logged in. One way would be to create a method in your activity which does the same thing you are doing in your **onCreateOptionsMenu**. When your users logins in from the login fragment, you simply call that method which will update your BottomNavigationMenu like so

```
//updateBottomNavigationMenu is the method that you have defined
(requireActivity() as MainActivity).updateBottomNavigationMenu()
```

**EDIT**

Here is what the updateBottomNavigationMenu method can look like. Note: You will have to save the instance of your menu when onCreateOptionsMenu is called.

```
fun updateBottomNavigationMenu() {
    If Logged {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_profile, menu)
    } else {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_login, menu)
    }
    
    bottomBar.setupWithNavController(menu!!, navController)
}
```

Comment: `updateBottomNavigationMenu()` is red symbol

Comment: @Jennifer you have to make that method yourself

Comment: Any help? Any link